# gslshell(lua based) returns 0/0 ==0/0 true

Tags: performance, gcc, lua, floating-point

In gsl-shell ( [a luajit based interface to gsl](http://www.nongnu.org/gsl-shell/)), I got

```
> 0/0==0/0
true
```

while it is `false` from Lua 5.1.
Why is it? Does this discrepancy come from Luajit vs Lua, GSL library, or the gsl-shell interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asked on gsl-shell mailing list. found that

> That's because gsl-shell is compiled with the -ffast-math flag,
>   which(surprisingly!) disables nans and infs.[1](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/gsl-shell-info/2014-01/msg00001.html)

Per [GCC manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.0/gcc/Optimize-Options.html), I guess this option should not be turned on for such a numerical application like GSL-Shell.

*-ffast-math
    Sets -fno-math-errno, -funsafe-math-optimizations,
    -fno-trapping-math, -ffinite-math-only, -fno-rounding-math, -fno-signaling-nans and fcx-limited-range.
   This option causes the preprocessor macro **FAST_MATH** to be defined.
   This option should never be turned on by any -O option since it can result in incorrect output for programs which depend on an exact implementation of IEEE or ISO rules/specifications for math functions.*

Answer (score 2):

Quick testing indicates that this is gsl-shell. lua5.1 and lua5.2 (from debian), lua 5.1 (self-compiled on CentOS 5) and luajit (from git master, self-compiled on debian) all give the proper behaviour (and return `nan` when the result of `0/0` is printed directly. The current build of gsl-shell (for Windows) has the behaviour you indicated and returns `-2147483648` when the result of `0/0` is printed.

I can't explain it (or even theorize about it really) but it certainly seems to be a gsl-shell problem.